# Do bound parameters get escaped using the Core/Resource model?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, security, sql, parameter

Consider the following example:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$email_address = $_GET['email'];

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `email_address` = ?';
$bar = $connection->fetchAll($sql, $email_address);
```

Does Magento handle escaping automatically, based on the bound parameters — or would this code be susceptible to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Source: [How to mysql escape in magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132797/how-to-mysql-escape-in-magento)

> I think Magento uses a DB Access layer based on PDO, which handles escaping automatically provided you use bound parameters.

When looking at `Mage_Core_Model_Resource`, the `getConnection` method states:

```
/**
 * Creates a connection to resource whenever needed
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface
 */
```

When looking at `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Interface.php`, the following comment is visible for the `fetchOne` method:

```
 /**
 * Safely quotes a value for an SQL statement.
 *
 * If an array is passed as the value, the array values are quoted
 * and then returned as a comma-separated string.
 *
 * @param mixed $value The value to quote.
 * @param mixed $type  OPTIONAL the SQL datatype name, or constant, or null.
 * @return mixed An SQL-safe quoted value (or string of separated values).
 */
```

This seems to imply that the parameters are safely escaped. The same comments aren't visible on the other fetch methods (i.e `fetchRow`, `fetchAll` etc).

Thus, would parsing user input values into the SQL statement using the `fetchOne`, `fetchRow`, `fetchAll` methods be susceptible to SQL injection — or would the parameters be safely escaped by the Variant Interface?

Comment: I think you can simply test this with `$email_address = "email-with-single'quote"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment.
I think it's safe to assume the parameters are escaped properly.
Tried these 3 cases:

**Case 1:**

```
$email_address = "email-with-single'quote";
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `customer_entity` WHERE `email` = ?';
$bar = $connection->fetchAll($sql, $email_address);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($bar);exit;
exit;
```

Result is an empty array.

**Case 2:**

```
$email_address = "email-with-single'quote";

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `customer_entity` WHERE `email` = '.$email_address;
$bar = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($bar);exit;
exit;
```

Result:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-single'quote' at line 1 in /[ROOT]/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234

**Case 3:**

```
$email_address = "email-with-single'quote";

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `customer_entity` WHERE `email` = \''.$email_address.'\'';
$bar = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($bar);exit;
```

Result: Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'quote'' at line 1 in /[ROOT]/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234

**In other words**...
When using the unescaped email address directly, I get an error because of the single quote.
when using the email address as a parameter the query executes properly.